# LibCurl HTML to string

Tags: c++, libcurl

I would like help in getting a website's HTML source and putting it into a string. That way I can search through the string and find certain text. The links to the pages will be put in a separate text file.

This is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("profiles.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        { 
            Get_Html(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

void Get_Html(string link)
{
    size_t found;
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        // Tell libcurl the URL 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link);
        // Tell libcurl what function to call when it has data 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,);
        // Do it! 
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        if (res == 0)
        {
            found = contents.find("Currently Online");
            if (found != std::string::npos){
                cout << "Currently Online!" << endl;
            }
            found = contents.find("Currently In-Game");
            if (found != std::string::npos){
                cout << "Currently In-Game!" << endl;
            }
            found = contents.find("Offline");
            if (found != std::string::npos){
                cout << "Currently Offline!" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "NAH!!!" << endl;
        }

        else
            cerr << "Error: " << res << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your setting of `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is incomplete. Is it that you need help with? Something else?

Comment: That is the part I would like help on. The examples I have been looking at take in a char*. Is there a way I can convert a string to a char*? 
Since I am taking a string from a .txt file. (the website url)

Comment: I need a way to have LibCurl download HTML and put it into a string that I initiated titled "content". Can you help me?

Comment: I think you need to do some more searching, both here on SO and on your favorite search engine, as doing this has been done many times and there are many examples on how to do this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl_easy` is going to read some data into its own buffer, and pass that to your callback as a `char *`.  You can take that data and then append it to your string (which you can pass in as userdata).  Appending a char array to a string should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

you need the following function to turn the HTML output in to a string:

```
size_t write_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream) {
((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size*count);
return size*count;
}
```

and then in the `Get_Html` function:

```
string response;
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
```

So your code should look like this:

```
size_t write_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream) {
((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size*count);
return size*count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("profiles.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        { 
            Get_Html(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

void Get_Html(string link)
{
    size_t found;
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {


        string response;
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

        // Tell libcurl the URL 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link);
        // Tell libcurl what function to call when it has data 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,);
        // Do it! 
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        if (res == 0)
        {
            found = contents.find("Currently Online");
            if (found != std::string::npos){
                cout << "Currently Online!" << endl;
            }
            found = contents.find("Currently In-Game");
            if (found != std::string::npos){
                cout << "Currently In-Game!" << endl;
            }
            found = contents.find("Offline");
            if (found != std::string::npos){
                cout << "Currently Offline!" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "NAH!!!" << endl;
        }

        else
            cerr << "Error: " << res << endl;
    }

}
```